# Fix the code to get rid of ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length

Tags: python, pandas

I have been getting the following error, when I am trying to conditionally update a dataframe column from values from another column.

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value.
```

I haven't been able to figure out the cause after spending hours. Here is the simplified code to demonstrate the issue:

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame({'jim': [0, 0, 1, 1],
                    'joe': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'y'],
                    'jolie': np.random.rand(4), 
                    'folie': np.random.rand(4)})

dfm = dfm.set_index(['jim', 'joe'])

dfm.loc[(dfm['jolie'] == 1) , 'jolie'] = dfm['folie']
```

As soon as I remove the index the last line of code above works. My questions is: What am I doing wrong? Can the above code be fixed without removing the index? Is this a bug in pandas?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it's not a bug in pandas. It's just not clear at all what you are trying to do here. I think you perhaps want `groupby` but it's not clear to me what setting the index achieves

Comment: `dfm['jolie'] == 1` is almost always false, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the data values in the code are just for illustration of the error. the dataframe I am using can have million of rows and data mostly as strings. In my original data, I have merged 2 dataframes based on the multi-level index and then updating values present in first data frame using the values from the second dataframe when the values in first data frame meet certain criteria. I get this error irrespective of whatever conditional logic I use and irrespective of whether the underlying column as part of the condition is string or numeric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here might very well be because the length of `dfm.loc[(dfm['jolie'] == 1) , 'jolie']` is different that that of `dfm['folie']` since the former only looks at a sub-series of `dfm['jolie']`.

In addition, when assigning values of a series to another, the indexes of the two must match, whether they are single- or multi-index.

For example, the following would work:

```
dfm.loc[(dfm['jolie'] == 1) , 'jolie'] = dfm.loc[(dfm['jolie'] == 1) ,'folie']
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. Although i don't understand why presence of index makes the difference.

Comment: like I said, that tells pandas just to look at the positions where it's True. Without it, it gives the whole series, so you cannot assign a,b,c = v,w,x,y,z. Similar to the `too many values to unpack` in pure Python. Also, if it works, consider accepting the answer.